# iphone autorotation black background

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiactionsheet

I use OpenGLView to display content of my app but sometimes I have to display UIActionSheet.
My application works on both - landscape and portrait mode - but since it's OpenGL view I handle rotation of the view by myself so to display UIActionSheet I use empty view and add actionsheet to it. the problem is that when I use shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation everything works well but the animation of rotation (the black background on the edges of the screen) doesn't match visually to the rest of the application.
Is there a way to change that background or turn off the animation (set it's time to 0?) but still let the OS to handle the rotation of the view?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what your asking, and this is what works for me:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

Where "blackColor" is the color you want to set the background.

Comment: nope - that's not the thing. actually I have background color set to to clear. but those black edges are independent from view's background color.